# Quickblox: analog of "push" method in the RESTful API

Tags: quickblox

In the Quickblox RESTful API there's a special update operator "push" that appends specified values to array.
Is there any analog in the Quickblox iOS SDK that doesn't require to send the whole array to the server to update one value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help

```
QBCOCustomObject *object = [QBCOCustomObject customObject];
object.className = @"SuperSample";
object.ID = @"51d5a979efa357c7fa000006";

NSMutableDictionary *specialUpdateParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[specialUpdateParams setObject:@"phone" forKey:@"push[interests]"];

[QBCustomObjects updateObject:object specialUpdateOperators:specialUpdateParams delegate:self];
```

Feel free to try Snippets  https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/snippets

This project contains lots of examples